# SQL Unable to Insert Converted DateTime in Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, command-text

I am puzzled why I am unable to insert a converted date value into my table column when the output of it is the same.

**Error:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion failed when converting date and/or
>   time from character string

**Success (hard coded DateTime):**

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [TestDB].[Cat1].[Table1] (CreatedOn) 
                    VALUES ('2019-08-22 23:59:59.000')";
```

**Failed (converted DateTime):**

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [TestDB].[Cat1].[Table1] (CreatedOn) 
                    VALUES ('@CreatedOn')";

//value below has the same output as above (2019-08-22 23:59:59.000)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedOn", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"));

//below failed too
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedOn", DateTime.Now);
```

**Column Type:**

[image]

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6c32d05795580d94d19b85fedc57031 your quesry working fine check your column datatype

Comment: my column datatype is correct.

Comment: `VALUES ('@CreatedOn')"` are you sure? It should be `cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [TestDB].[Cat1].[Table1] (CreatedOn)  VALUES (@CreatedOn)";` no quotes around the param name.

Comment: try specifying datatype, cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

Comment: You *assume* the OP is American @ZaynulAbadinTuhin. Considering the time of date they are posting, that's unlikely. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `'2019-08-22 23:59:59.000'` is **not** unambiguous with the `datetime` datatype (it is with the new date and time datatypes). If, for example, you're English then the below will fail:

```
SET LANGUAGE BRITISH;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2019-08-22 23:59:59.000');
```

This is because SQL Server reads the date in the format `yyyy-dd-MM`, and there aren't 22 months in the year. As noted though, it works fine with the newer data types, or if you're American (but you *should* be writing language agnostic code):

```
SET LANGUAGE BRITISH; --English
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(3),'2019-08-22 23:59:59.000');
SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),'2019-08-22 23:59:59.000');

SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH; --American. Confusing, right? :)
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2019-08-22 23:59:59.000');
```

One way is to use an unambiguous format, which isn't affected by data type or language:

```
SET LANGUAGE BRITISH;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2019-08-22T23:59:59.000');
```

Otherwise you can tell SQL Server the [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles) of the value (in this case `121`):

```
SET LANGUAGE BRITISH;
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2019-08-22 23:59:59.000',121);
```